# Creating tag cloud using pure HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html, css, tags, cloud

I want to create a word cloud as seen in this image :
[enter link description here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-QskKbp99nU0/U7Z55m1xueI/AAAAAAAAB5Y/Yu3HF0o4PKM/s1600/tags.jpg)

How can i proceed to create a tag cloud with out using javascript ? Just HTML5 and CSS3. Thanks.

Some one has solution ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use div's and change text alignments positions etc.. with CSS. example if u have div1 u need set text format with css for div1.

```
http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/a/aa011407.htm
```